# How to change Tkinter button image on click?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two images for a single button and also I created buttons with images. I would like to change the button image whenever I first click it. For example when I click the button I want button image to change "UnclickedImage" to "ClickedImage".

I could not be able to find any similar question in stackoverflow.

```
from tkinter import *


class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, tk=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.tk = tk
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.photoTodo = PhotoImage(file="./Images/TodoUnClicked.png")
        Button(self.tk, image=self.photoTodo).pack(side=LEFT)
        self.photoStayFocussed = PhotoImage(file="./Images/StayFoccusedUnClicked.png")
        Button(self.tk, image=self.photoStayFocussed).pack(side=RIGHT)


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.configure(bg='white')
    ex = Example(root)
    root.title('')
    root.iconbitmap('./Images/empty.ico')
    root.geometry("400x100+300+300")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a custom button class.

```
class ImageButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, image1, image2, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unclickedImage = PhotoImage(file = image1)
        self.clickedImage = PhotoImage(file = image2)
        super().__init__(master, *args, image = self.unclickedImage, **kwargs)
        self.toggleState = 1
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.clickFunction)
    def clickFunction(self, event = None):
        if self.cget("state") != "disabled": #Ignore click if button is disabled
            self.toggleState *= -1
            if self.toggleState == -1:
                self.config(image = self.clickedImage)
            else:
                self.config(image = self.unclickedImage)
```

This takes the widget master and the first and second image paths as arguments, creates the `PhotoImage` objects and then instantiates a button with the unclicked image.
There is a binding to `<Button-1>`, which is left click, and this changes the image when the button is clicked. The `toggleState` variable keeps track of the current image showing so when the button is clicked the opposite image is shown.
You can incorporate this in to your current program like this:

```
from tkinter import *

class ImageButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, master, image1, image2, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unclickedImage = PhotoImage(file = image1)
        self.clickedImage = PhotoImage(file = image2)
        super().__init__(master, *args, image = self.unclickedImage, **kwargs)
        self.toggleState = 1
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.clickFunction)
    def clickFunction(self, event = None):
        if self.cget("state") != "disabled": #Ignore click if button is disabled
            self.toggleState *= -1
            if self.toggleState == -1:
                self.config(image = self.clickedImage)
            else:
                self.config(image = self.unclickedImage)

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        ImageButton(self, "./Images/TodoUnClicked.png", "./Images/TodoClicked.png").pack(side=LEFT)
        ImageButton(self, "./Images/StayFoccusedUnClicked.png", "./Images/StayFoccusedClicked.png").pack(side=RIGHT)


def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.configure(bg='white')
    ex = Example(root)
    ex.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
    root.title('')
    root.geometry("400x100+300+300")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note I also fixed your `Example` class as you weren't using it quite right. When you inherit a tkinter object, you pass the master to `super().__init__` and then use `self` as the parent of the children.

Comment: why don't you use `self.config(command=self.clickFunction)` instead of `self.bind("<Button-1>", self.clickFunction)`?

Comment: They might want to pass a command to the button, and that would override it, whereas a binding will not.

Comment: well, it is doable even even then, but this is simpler, except then you probably want to also add a check for button state so to not call the function when button is disabled (`if self.cget('state') == 'disabled': return` at the start of `clickFunction`)

Comment: Ty Nice Answer.